# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TikTokAPI'

Tags: python, scrape, tiktok

I already followed The Unofficial TikTok API in Python installation guide and write `from TikTokApi import TikTokApi`, it worked well yesterday despite errors related to 'Region'. However, I run the code again but it throws an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TikTokAPI'` which is weird because I obviously wrote `from TikTokApi import TikTokApi` not `from TikTokApi import TikTokAPI`

Comment: `pip install TikTokApi` ? Any virtual environment?

Comment: I already run `pip install TikTokApi` as it is shown in the guide. I already set my venv and activate it. Here is the version `virtualenv 20.13.0 from C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py`